Terraform for RDS DB user credentials rotation using aws-mananged ('prebuilt') Lambda
In this AWS Document it is stated that it's possible to setup database (aurora-postgres in my case) secret rotation based on a pre-baked Lambda template (details may be found in this AWS Document).
It is fairly simple to follow these steps in the Web Console.
Among others, the outcome is a managed Lambda Function (AFAIK wrapped within a SAM Application) along with its' helper resources like IAM::ServiceRole etc. that gets created.
My question is: is it possible to recreate the same setup in Terraform?
I couldn't find any examples + I cannot find the corresponding aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation attributes.
Details:
tf version = 1.9
aws Provider version = 5.62

In advance thanks for the answers! Cheers!

As far as I know, you no longer have to use the Lambda function. If you configure your DB to use the manage_master_user_password option, the rotation is automatic. There are some limitations outlined in the Aurora docs.

That's true but the question relates to other-than-root_user password /credentials.

And what is the issue then with the aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation resource?

You need to manually define the Lamda::Function in the tf code along with its' helper resources and then reference it in aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation, then maintain it etc.
But Im almost certain at this point that this is necessary as there's no way to invoke this AWS-managed SAM Function in the context of DB-secrets rotation.

Yup, that's why I was asking.
